# SpriteKit - How to render to an existing texture

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, textures

In SpriteKit, how can you render a scene to an *existing* texture?

There is this method `textureFromNode:` of `SKView` that renders the scene to a texture, but it is creating a new texture. I want to avoid this overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no such API, meaning you would have to use an `SKMutableTexture` object and update the pixel data yourself using the `-modifyPixelDataWithBlock:` method.

However, this would very likely be more expensive than getting a new `SKTexture` object from the API you mentioned. From the [`SKMutableTexture` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skmutabletexture):

> Normally, SpriteKit textures (SKTexture objects) are static, meaning that once created, their contents cannot be changed. This is important because a static image can be more efficiently managed inside the graphics hardware. However, sometimes you need to be able to update the contents of a texture dynamically. In this case, you should use a mutable texture. Because there is a performance penalty for updating the texture’s contents, consider other options first. For example, you can render a texture in hardware using the texture(from:) method and a node tree.

If texture creation is actually a verifiable bottleneck through instrumentation, you might have to look into other options of working aournd this.